# Ordered insertion into linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to write a program that inserts strings in order, such as when i insert dog and cat, regardless of the order I insert them, it should return cat, dog.
As of now when I do it, it isn't inserting in order, it's inserting just like normal. I'm pretty sure my method for switching the head and current works because earlier, it would flip my input, whether it was supposed to or not So if it was supposed to be cat dog, it would return dog cat. For whatever reason it gets to my if statement, it's almost like it skips it. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void insert(String s){
    head= new node(s,head);
    node current=head.getNext();
    if(current == null){
        current=head;
        while(current.getNext() != null){
            if(current.getData().compareTo(s)>0){
                current.setNext(head);
                head.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
                head=current;
                current=head;
            }
            current= current.getNext();
        }
    }else{
        while(current.getNext() != null){
            if(current.getData().compareTo(s)>0){
                current.setNext(head);
                head.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());
                head=current;
                current=head;
            }
            current=current.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your list using `java.util.Collections` class
**Ex:**

```
Collections.sort(your_list);
```

Comment: I could but honestly this is a hw assignment and we're not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code and the logic. I will give hints for fixing below

1. Everytime you call insert you create a new `head` for the list (I presume a field of your class). that's not how linkedlists work. You should only create a new `head` when `head` is `null` (empty list)
2. You are setting `current` to the next node after the newly created `head`. Therefore it will have whatever value the constructor of `node` assigned to it. If it assigns a default value of `null`, you will never get into the else part of the if statement.
3. According to the above you will inevitably get in the first of the if statement where you reassign `current` from `null` to `head`. Then you are basically comparing the data (String) of the same node (head) and you never get in the next if.

So basically the function you wrote is equivalent to this (try it out)

```
public void insert(String s) {
    head = new node(s, head);
    node current = head.getNext();
}
```

Which is probably not what you intended. Start changing your code by only creating `head` when it is null and then return after that (if list only has one element no need to swap). Then insert a new node after head and swap if needed.

Comment: What should I do regarding current then? I'm a little confused on that part.